# Tikz: append arrow at end of plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I would like to append an arrow at the end of my plot, in the direction of the path.

Here my snippet:

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \draw[line width=2pt, color=red, smooth,domain=0.2*pi:0.8*pi,->]  plot (\x,{0.75*sin(\x r)});
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But unfortunately, the arrow looks straight up, instead of looking along the path.

Comment: I think your snippet won't compile with `>` only; try with `->`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino, thanks I corrected my snippet. The problem remains.

Comment: Short answer: Put `\def\pgf@plot@curveto@handler@finish{%
  \ifpgf@plot@started%
    \pgfpathcurvebetweentimecontinue{0}{0.995}{\pgf@plot@curveto@first}{\pgf@plot@curveto@first@support}{\pgf@plot@curveto@second}{\pgf@plot@curveto@second}%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother` in your preamble.

Comment: @Jake Thanks for the link! Indeed its solved by this! :)